# PyArrow dataset S3 performance different with PyArrow filesystem, s3fs, indirect copy

Tags: pyarrow

I have a 2.3GB newline-delimited JSON file in an S3 bucket.  My goal is to parse the data using a specified schema and write it out to a parquet file (this question considers a single file, my actual production use case involves multiple files).

My core approach is to define a dataset against the `.jsonl` file with `myds = pyarrow.dataset(...)`, then write it out as parquet with `pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset(myds ...)`.

I have tested the following three implementations (imports and other extraneous details omitted to make the code less noisy):

###### 1 Let PyArrow handle the filesystem

```py
myds= ds.dataset(
    srcpath,
    format='json',
    schema=schema
)
ds.write_dataset(
    myds, 
    destpath, 
    format='parquet',
    ... other write options
)
```

###### 2 Give PyArrow the filesystem

Specify the `filesystem` argument for the `dataset` and `write_dataset` methods as a separately defined `s3fs.S3FileSystem` object.

```py
s3fsys = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

myds = ds.dataset(
    srcpath,
    format='json',
    schema=schema,
    filesystem=s3fsys
)
ds.write_dataset(
    myds, 
    destpath, 
    format='parquet',
    filesystem=s3fsys
    ... other write options
)
```

###### 3 PyArrow works locally, handle download/upload separately

I am using the `smart_open` library for the file transfer between S3 and local.

```py
def transfer_file(source: str, destination: str, chunk_size: int = 10*2**20):
    with (
        smart_open.open(source, 'rb') as fin,
        smart_open.open(destination, 'wb') as fout
    ):
        while True:
            chunk = fin.read(chunk_size)
            if not chunk:
                break
            fout.write(chunk)

transfer_file(
    s3src,
    localsrc
)

myds = ds.dataset(
    localsrc,
    format='json',
    schema=schema
)

ds.write_dataset(
    myds, 
    localdest, 
    format='parquet',
    ... other write options
)

transfer_file(
    localdestfile,
    s3dest
)
```

I observed significant differences in the processing times for the three approaches (numbers below stayed pretty consistent over multiple runs):

- PyArrow determines filesystem: 223s
- Give PyArrow the filesystem: 70s
- Handle download/upload separately: 30s (includes the time for the `smart_open` download/upload)

Why is there such a big performance difference?  Using the first approach keeps my code simpler but for my actual dataset (a couple of TB) the difference in time would be significant.  I'm not sure if I'm just missing some options that I could provide to `pyarrow.dataset` to make it more performant out of the box.

Comment: Have you also tried passing the arrow implementation of the s3 file system? https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#s3

Comment: @0x26res I have not tried that, but I did find an approach (posted below as an answer) that helped.

Comment: I think it should be faster than with the s3fs implementation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.scanner` ([documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.scanner)) has various options to tweak how the dataset is read.  I was able to get better performance with the approaches **1 Let PyArrow handle the filesystem** and **2 Give PyArrow the filesystem** by creating a scanner from the dataset with higher values for `batch_size` and `batch_readahead`:

```py
myds= ds.dataset(
    srcpath,
    format='json',
    schema=schema
)
scanner = myds.scanner(
    batch_size=8*10**6,
    batch_readahead=32
)
ds.write_dataset(
    scanner, 
    destpath, 
    format='parquet',
    ... other write options
)
```

Tweaking those parameters allows me to make the tradeoff between memory consumption and speed.

Comparing between the approaches 1 and 2, for the same parameters for the `scanner`, approach 2 (providing PyArrow with the filesystem) still seems to outperform approach 1.  I'm not sure why, but providing the filesystem doesn't overly complicate my code and the performance is good enough so I'm not going to dig further.